# FlexLM 9.2 on Solaris 9?

Tags: solaris, licensing

Is FlexLM 9.2 supported on Solaris 9?

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be. Here's the [users guide](http://www.quantumwise.com/documents/FLEXlm/FLEXlm_End_User_Guide.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the lnk, however I made a typo in my original question - I meant FlexLm 9.2 not 9.5.